# Why aren't windows constants included in .net?

Tags: .net, windows, constants

Every time I see code calling into say kernel32.dll or User32.dll the snippet always, even on MSDN, requires the developer to hard code any required constants (WM_SETREDRAW = 11 for example) into the routine. Since these constants never change by definition and have one standard definition always, why doesn't .net provide them somewhere? I feel like we all end up creating our own libraries of constants and standard Windows dll calls as we need them. It seems like this duplication of effort is wasteful and prone to error.

Perhaps I haven't looked hard enough and they are all in there somewhere, if so could someone please provide their location?

Comment: .Net was never meant as a replacement for the win32 api.

Comment: Hell, why don't they just go the whole hog and provide .net implementation of User32 and Kernal32 for us.

Comment: [With the right tool it becomes less error prone](http://pinvoke.net/). Not all apps use these DLLs and there are loads of other DLLs that apps use. It becomes the discussion between "what's common" and "what's not" and "what would add value". Defining them on the off-chance they are used probably had less value than leaving it up to the developer. They would also inherit maintenance responsibilities on a task that is likely better suited to being an Open Source library somewhere.

Comment: When I was first introduced to .NET I wondered the same thing, +1

Answer (score 2):

Only the .Net team can provide the actual answer I think, we can only make assumptions.

There probably are many reasons. Here are some guesses:

- Win32 API is too much error-prone. Lots of Win32 methods require the developer to manipulate unsafe handles (often represented as `IntPtr` objects), which is not the .Net-way of doing things (for instance you should use FileStream instead of `CreateFile`/`ReadFile`/`WriteFile`/`CloseHandle`)
- there is no point in adding the whole Win32 API in mscorlib in only 0.1% of developers actually use it
- Microsoft prefer developers write managed code
- The .Net framework is designed to be platform agnostic. That's why you'll find [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) for example (`A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.`). So adding the whole Win32 API makes no sense.

Microsoft added some Windows-specific classes in the [`Microsoft.Win32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145011) namespace , but it's very limited and those functions are essential (registry operations, filedialogs...).

Concerning pinvoke.net, I wouldn't rely too much on it. I often see poorly written method declarations that would crash on x64 systems (`int` instead of `IntPtr`, struct layout issues...). Another example: the [`WriteFile`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writefile) method declarations are inconsistent. `SafeHandle` vs `IntPtr`...etc.

Comment: While I understand the preference that we write managed code, and that .net should be in theory be machine independent (even though mono project et al are not supported) the fact is so much of the windows API (or in the generic sense the operating system API) is not accessible through .net. Having a library of constants would seemingly cost nothing, be trivial to maintain and useful in thousands of applications. Regarding poor implementations, and even the fact there's about four different ways to access a dll, .net doesn't prevent poor implementations anywhere, testing is the only answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's not just a single reason, there are many.  I can think of any of the following playing a role in the decision to not include them:

- not even the teams that worked on the framework assemblies shared a common set of pinvoke declarations, every team wrote their own
- Microsoft maintains only a single source for the winapi, the Windows SDK
- the maintainers of the SDK are a different group, not closely related to any of the groups that worked on .NET
- there's not just one winapi, it is heavily dependent on the target Windows version, something you specify when you build a C/C++ program.  This goes heavily against the grain of .NET, it is version agnostic
- the winapi is enormous, nobody will be pleased with just a partial version
- the pinvoke declaration for a winapi function is often rewritten from its original form to make the usage much simpler.  Particularly the case with the kind of functions that take opaque pointers, SendMessage() is the classic example
- .NET was designed to ensure you don't have to take a dependency on the winapi.  You can anyway with your own pinvoke declarations to back-fill missing parts, but the guarantee that this will work on any Windows version that can run a .NET program is lost.  Windows 98 and 2000 are still officially supported for 2.0

You can use the [Pinvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) tool.  The declarations it provides are auto-generated from the Windows SDK headers.

Comment: While I understand that a straight 1:1 mapping of .net functions to winapi function would somewhat defeat the purpose of .net being system agnostic, having available at least the constants seems to be a very low risk and low effort addition to the framework, allowing people to at least more robustly make those additional calls themselves.

Comment: Though considering your main thrust, when writing .net projects we actively manage our own references and dependencies already and so take full responsibility for the dependencies we tie to. Providing the windows API directly would be one option we would need to consider when writing applications.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say.  But sure, it's always fine when a programmer takes responsibility.  Leaving it up to a vendor creates greater expectations.

Answer (score 0):

.NET was designed to be a complete ecosystem. Dropping into the Windows API is a hack, and not including the constants is Microsoft's way of discouraging it.

Comment: How is P/Invoke a hack? For instance, you can't use memory mapped files in .Net 2/3/3.5 without P/Invoke. And there are still many things you can't do with .Net 4.5.